# no me funcionan las instrucciones poo con apache2

Tags: php, apache, poo

yo tenia instalado xampp y funcionaba mi codigo de un menu correctamente usando Programacion Orientada a Objetos, tuve que reinstalar mi sistema pero ahora instale apache2 php5 y mysql. Los codigos no fueron modificados, y no me funcionan.

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <?php
    class urls{
      private $archivo_actual; 
      public function urls($archivo){
        $this->archivo_actual=$archivo;
      }
      public function acti($boton){
        if ($boton==$this->archivo_actual){
          echo ('class="active"');
        }else{
          echo (' ');
        }
      }
      public function url( $sitio){ //para usar con las otras paginas.
        if($this->archivo_actual=='index.php'){
          echo 'href="pages/'.$sitio.'"';
        }else{
          echo 'href="'.$sitio.'"';
        }
      }
      public function urli(){ //para usar desde la principañ
        if ($this->archivo_actual=="index.php") {
          echo 'href=index.php';
        }else{
          echo 'href="../index.php"';
        }
      }
    }
    $ur = new urls(basename($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])); //obtenemos la url y la mandamos
  ?>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Desplegar navegación</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="">SmanTech</a>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

    <li <? $ur->acti("index.php"); ?>>
      <a <? $ur->urli("index.php"); ?>> Home</a>
    </li>
      <li <? $ur->acti("equi.php"); ?>>
        <a <? $ur->url("equi.php"); ?> > Equipos </a>
      </li>
      <li <? $ur->acti("dep.php"); ?>>
        <a <? $ur->url("dep.php"); ?>> Dependencias </a>
      </li>
      <li <? $ur->acti("tec.php"); ?>>
        <a <? $ur->url("tec.php"); ?>> Tecnicos </a>
      </li>
      <li <? $ur->acti("solc.php"); ?>>
        <a <? $ur->url("solc.php"); ?>> Solicitudes </a>
      </li >
      <li <? $ur->acti("hist.php"); ?>>
        <a <? $ur->url("hist.php"); ?>> Historiales </a>
      </li>
      
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <!-- <li><a href="#">Enlace #3</a></li> -->
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
          <? echo $_SESSION['user']; ?> <b class="caret"></b>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Configuracion</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Acción #2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Acción #3</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a <? $ur->url("logout.php"); ?>>Cerrar Sesión</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Esto es lo que sucede cuando uso este codigo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Haciendo uso de mis poderes mágicos, puedo ver que no se está ejecutando el interprete de php, y por tanto Apache está sirviendo el fichero tal como está almacenado en el disco, sin interpretar el código fuente del script. Puedes confirmarlo al ver el código fuente de la página que se ha servido al navegador.

Esto puede estar ocurriendo básicamente por 2 razones:

### No carga el módulo de php

Apache no está cargando el módulo del interprete de php. Para resolverlo, edita el archivo `httpd.conf`, de acuerdo a la [documentación](http://php.net/manual/es/install.windows.legacy.index.php):

```
#   
LoadModule php5_module "c:/php/php5apache2.dll"
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php

# Configurar la ruta de php.ini
PHPIniDir "C:/php"
```

> Nota: Recuerda sustituir la ruta de acceso actual a PHP para el C:/php/ en los ejemplos anteriores. Tenga cuidado en utilizar ya sea php5apache2.dll o php5apache2_2.dll en la directiva LoadModule y verificar que el fichero de referencia se encuentra localizado en la ruta de fichero que se señala en la presente directiva.

También puede ocurrir que si carga el módulo pero

### No se ejecuta el interprete para tu archivo

En Apache generalmente se utiliza una o varias reglas sobre la extensión del archivo para decidir que se procesa por el interprete de php y que no.

Esto se configura también en `httpd.conf`. Busca o añade reglas como:

```
#Los archivos con extensión .php se procesarán con php
<FilesMatch \.php$>
      SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```